# how to rotate a seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I rotate a `seaborn.lineplot` so that the result will be as a function of y and not a function of x.

For example, this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[0,2],[0,1.5],[1,1],[1,5]], columns=['group','val'])
sns.lineplot(x='group',y='val',data=df)
```

Create this figure:

[image]

But is there a way to rotate the figure in 90° ? so that in the X we will have "val" and in Y we will have "group" and the std will go from left to right and not from bottom to up.

Thanks

**EDIT: I've opened a ticket in seaborn to ask for this feature: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1661**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what you'd do if not using seaborn. You would calculate the mean and standard deviation and plot those as a function of the group. Now it is quite straight forward to exchange x and y for a `plot(x,y)`: `plot(y,x)`. For the filled region, you can use `fill_betweenx` instead of `fill_between`.

Below the two cases for comparisson.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[0,2],[0,1.5],[1,1],[1,5]], columns=['group','val'])

mean = df.groupby("group").mean()
std = df.groupby("group").std()

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax.plot(mean.index, mean["val"].values)
ax.fill_between(mean.index, (mean-std)["val"].values, (mean+std)["val"].values, alpha=.5)
ax.set(xlabel="group", ylabel="val")

ax2.plot(mean["val"].values, mean.index)
ax2.fill_betweenx(mean.index, (mean-std)["val"].values, (mean+std)["val"].values, alpha=.5)
ax2.set(ylabel="group", xlabel="val")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so if you (130k rep) say that it is not possible from within seaborn I understand I have to find a workaround. Thanks

Comment: Well, the workaround is (for example) this answer. Also consider that even in the "non-transposed" case, separation of data aggregation and plotting has a lot of advantages. Anyways, a possible alternative may be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700336/how-to-flip-axes-on-seaborn-tsplot-plot/42718655#42718655) where the data from the plot is extracted and transposed.

Comment: Thanks, as this feature does not exist in seaborn I'll accept your answer

Comment: This answer would be clearer if it began with saying that this feature does not exist in Seaborn.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [seaborn docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) on `lineplot`, the dataframe passed to `data` must be

> Tidy (“long-form”) dataframe where each column is a variable and each row is an observation.

Which seems to imply there is no way to force the axes to switch, even by manipulating the data. If there is a way to do that I haven't found it - I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but one way you could go about it is to do it by hand so to speak. Something like this would do the trick

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[0,2],[0,1.5],[1,1],[1,5]], columns=['group','val'])
group = df['group'].tolist()
val = df['val'].tolist()
yl = list()
yu = list()
avg = list()
ii = 0
while ii < len(group):   #Loop through all the groups
    g = group[ii]
    y0 = val[ii]
    y1 = val[ii]
    s = 0
    jj = ii
    while (jj < len(group) and group[jj] == g):
        s += val[jj]
        #This takes the min and max, but could easily take the standard deviation
        if val[jj] > y1:
            y1 = val[jj]
        if val[jj] < y0:
            y0 = val[jj]
        jj += 1
    avg.append(s/(jj - ii))
    ii = jj
    yl.append(y0)
    yu.append(y1)

x = np.linspace(min(group), max(group), len(yl))
plt.ylabel(df.columns[0])
plt.xlabel(df.columns[1])
plt.plot(avg, x, color="#5a9edd", linestyle="-", linewidth=1.5)
plt.fill_betweenx(x, yl, yu, alpha=0.3)
```

This will give you the following plot:

[image]

For brevity this uses the minimum and maximum from each group to give the error band, but that can be easily changed to standard error or standard deviation as needed.